# Are services created in advance before needed by the controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I was reading a book which says:

> When the application starts, ASP.NET Core creates a new instance of the `Startup` class and calls its `ConfigureServices` method so that the application can create its services and services are objects that provide functionality to other parts of the application

[image]

I'm a little bit confused, because it looks like a service/object is created before it is actually needed in a Controller.

Let's say there is only a Controller that required an `UptimeService` object and `CalculateController` (not default mapping controller) is the only controller that needs an `UptimeService` object, so I add:

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<UptimeService>();
   services.AddMvc();
}
```

Let's say we run the application with routing to `Home/Index` first, my questions are:

1. According to the picture above, an `UptimeService` is always created, even we don't go to `Calculate/Index` and because `CalculateController` is the only controller that needs an `UptimeService`, isn't it very inefficient?
2. I often hear 'register a service', is it the same thing as 'create a service'?

Comment: Q1: dependency instances will only be created when resolving their dependents. So , no , it will not create `UptimeService` at startup (based on current code shown). Q2: NO

Comment: Both your questions are really easy to test yourself. Just add a log line in the constructor of your singleton and in which scenarios it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q2. No, registering a service does not mean creating a service.
Registering a services only configures the IoC Container for dependency injection. It means that `services.AddSingleton<UptimeService>();` will not create an instance of `UptimeService`, it will only "configure" the IoC container so that it can provide you an instance of `UptimeService` when you ask for it.

Q1. Now that you know that "registering a service" and "creating a service" are two different things, in the `Startup` class you only register services therefore, instance of `UptimeService` will only be created when the controller which has dependency on `UptimeService` is created, and that controller will only be created when you make a HTTP request that routes to that controller.

Controllers are created on every request, but since you are adding your service as `Singleton`, the same instance of this service will be provided to the controllers, but new instance of the controller will be created on every request.

Comment: thank you for your concise answer. so that mean the "Services Created" in the picture is wrong and it should be "Services Registered"?

Comment: @slowjams yes. Can you tell me the name of the book that has that picture?